Qt creator добавления плагина '-plugin tslib' в запуск программы
Цель: запустить приложение (программу) из qt creator версии 4.14.1 с применением при запуски плагина '-plugin tslib'.
Я ожидаю получить от qt creator запуск аналогичный командной строке:
root@pi:~# /home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab -plugin tslib

При котором программа запускается верно и работает тачьскрин.
Путь где находиться программа:
/home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab

Название программы: kiab
Плагин: -plugin tslib
Что делал с qt creator:
Сначала подумал что нужно поставить галочку и добавить в 'сменить программу на устройстве:' /home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab -plugin tslib
Но на это получил сообщение об ошибки:
bash: /home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab -plugin tslib: Нет такого файла или каталога


Далее попытался добавить '-plugin tslib' в 'Параметры командной строки:'
На что получил сообщение:
ts_setup() failed (No such file or directory)


Стал разбираться почему и понял, что  qt creator не правильно команды формирует. Он сначала запускает без '-plugin tslib' '/home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab'
А после отсылает '-plugin tslib'
Симулировал в командной строке:
root@pi:~# /home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_clicked()
ts_setup() failed (No such file or directory)
ts_setup() failed (No such file or directory)

Добавляю новые нарытые данные:

запускается верно
/home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab -plugin tslib

запускается программа но не работает тач.
2.1 сначала запускаем программу
/home/pi/Qt_Projects/kiab/kiab


2.2 после отсылаем плагин.
-plugin tslib

2.3 получаем ошибки
ts_setup() failed (No such file or directory)

2.4 добавляю
TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1
TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ts0
QT_QPA_FB_TSLIB=1
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0

2.5 снова -plugin tslib все сьел а тач не заработал. Так в чем отличие запуска?
Прошу помощи в решение.
